# Passing a variable to chdir() in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, chdir

I'm having a problem with chdir() in my C program - only when running on Linux (works fine on Mac). I've stripped down my code.

Something like this works fine:

```
chdir("/Documents");
```

but when I try to pass it as a variable it doesn't want to work.

```
char *home_directory;
home_directory = malloc(80);
chdir(home_directory);
```

Home directory is read from a file elsewhere in my code, I can post how I've done that if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is "it doesn't want to work" the best demonstration of your ability to express a technical idea precisely to your peers?

Comment: (1) post the code filling `home_directory`. (2) what actually fails on Linux?

Comment: I expect that you do the reading of the home directory between the `malloc` and the `chdir`? Are you sure that 79 characters is enough for the path?

Comment: You should check what `chdir()` returns and what `errno` is set to afterwards (your program should probably handle errors this way regardless). `perror()` will show you a human-readable error message. I assume you have already inspected the value `home_directory` before the call to `chdir()`.

Comment: It is certain that the contents of the variable that you are passing as a parameter are wrong. Please try `strcpy(home_directory, "/Documents");` before the chdir in your code above.

Comment: The code sample as provided passes an uninitialized char array to chdir. The step to fill in the home_directory array needs to ensure that the string is NULL-terminated and doesn't exceed the 80 character array bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are reading `home_directory` from a file, have you forgotten to remove a trailing newline and any other spurious characters before you use it as a parameter to `chdir`?

Comment: I knew the problem was as something as trivial as this.

Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @user1038788: So if this is the correct answer why didn't you vote it up and mark it as accepted?

Comment: "Vote up requires 15 reputation".

I have now marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing some error checking, like this;

```
char *home_directory;
home_directory = malloc(80);
/* ...fill the home directory... */
if (chdir(home_directory) == -1)
   perror("chdir");
```

.. and then with a `man chdir` yo can look up the meaning of the error code.

Comment: The `errno` will almost certainly end up being `ENOENT`. The `strace` suggestion will likely prove more useful (in addition to giving `errno` without the need to rebuild ;-)

Comment: Sure, it is however really bad practice not checking your error codes and then double bad of complaining that it does not work... you can hardly expect people to be around with a strace every single time a system call is failing...

Answer (score 1):

Since `chdir` is a system call on Linux, you can simply use the `strace` program to see what your program really does. That doesn't free you from handling errors preoperly in your code; obviously. It just helps you to follow the actions that your program takes.